# Global.Micrsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationsServices... is not defined error BC30002

Tags: vb.net, .net-5, legacy-code

I'm converting some old legacy VB apps from .NET framework to .NET 5, and have worked through most of the issues, however, I'm lost on these:

```
Error   BC30002 Type 'Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ApplicationBase' is not defined.
Error   BC30002 Type 'Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.User' is not defined.
Error   BC30002 Type 'Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer' is not defined.
Error   BC30002 Type 'Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.Internal.ContextValue' is not defined.
```

VisualBasic 10.3.0 package is included in the project.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: We should never have to tell you to show us the code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, generally I would agree. However, in this case I have thousands of lines of code, and have no clue what specific code is producing those errors. Unlike most errors, I can't just double-click on those and have it open the offending code. And the error indicates the file is "vbc" - my ignorance is showing, but I have no idea what that indicates. The code is also proprietary to my company. If I could reproduce the issues I could provide sample code, but I wouldn't even know where to start in this case.

tl&dr: I don't know what code is producing the error, or the file "vbc".

Comment: That is all relevant information that should be included in a full and clear explanation of the problem. Exactly where the error is generated is always relevant so, if there's a specific reason that you can't provide that, that is relevant too.

Comment: How exactly are you performing this migration? It sounds like there is some `My` code somewhere that is not compatible with .NET 5. That was one of the last pieces added - VB WinForms was supported in .NET 3.1 but it wasn't surfaced because some VB specific features, including `My`, had not been implemented - so there may be critical differences that are preventing your old code upgrading.

Answer (score 16):

I came accross the same issue today trying to update a .net framework (4.6 but I guess it applies to 4.x generally) to .net 5 using Microsofts Upgrade assistent.

I found the solution in [this bug report on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30478):

Simply put, add the following to your newly created `.vbproj-file`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyType>Empty</MyType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Place at the end of of `.vbproj-file` just before `</Project>` end tag.

Comment: Take care you have not another <MyType> tag. I had <MyType>Windows</MyType>. You just have to update from "Windows" to "Empty".

Comment: Same issue... you can just delete <MyType>Windows</MyType>

Comment: This is supposed to be an .NET Core 3 milestone issue. I faced same issue in .NET 7 today and same fix -> <MyType>Empty</MyType> fixed it. I'm yet to figure out sideeffects.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that the answers provided so far only offer workarounds for this issue, rather than addressing its root cause. If you are encountering the `BC30002` error when upgrading legacy VB projects to .NetCore/.Net framework, I suggest adding `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` within the `<PropertyGroup>`, as shown below:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <MyType>Windows</MyType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Just a note, targeting net7.0 for WinForms app I had to add '-windows' in a <TargetFramework> as it was missing and complier didn't like it.